# Why does Google Docs still ask me for permission when people try to view my doc?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, permissions

I created a doc that I want anyone with a link to see. Here are the settings I used:

[image: My Google Docs settings]

I gave that link to people on my site.

For some reason, every week, I get emails from Google Docs saying that people want to access my document and need my permission.

This is what those emails look like.

[image: permission emails]

What can I do to keep people who I gave the link to from needing my permission?

Comment: These users have Google Accounts, are logged into those Accounts when they click the link, correct?

Comment: Oh, good questions. Victor, who's in the example above, used a gmail address to request access, so he has an account. I'm assuming he was logged in because the request came from his gmail address.

Comment: The screenshot indicates anyone with the link can comment that doesn't mean they have access to edit the file.  I would post an answer if it was on the correct website, simply put, your getting requests because they don't have permission to view the file.

Comment: @Ramhound If I give them access to comment, doesn't that imply that they also have access to view?

Answer (score 3):

Please try to isolate the issue when the user loses the permission:

1. Check the shared document showing in the "Shared With Me" in the google drive
2. Please compare the URL which is shared with the user and at your end
3. Ensure, the user is accessing from the google account to which it is shared
4. In your login, please check the shared document shown under "My Drive" in the google drive

Hope this will help you in addressing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix.

1. Click "share" your document on the top right.
2. Select "anyone with a link can edit"
3. Click the button "copy link"
4. Open a new email and address it to those who you want to share it with
5. Paste the link in the body of your email and enter whatever subject you want.
6. Send email, and enjoy collaboration

(Side note, you can normally see who is editing a particular cell. With this method, however, animal names will show up so you can't tell who made changes.)

If you simply add names to the list, it will require them to login. **As long as you directly email someone with the link**, it will work without a login.